# Qt window resize height to fit QLabel text

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to create a window which height should be equal to the height of the child QLabel, the QLabel can be set to any size text and setWrap is True. Here is my current code:

```py
class TextWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(230)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QLayout.SizeConstraint.SetMinimumSize)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non urna nisl. Integer venenatis aliquet faucibus. Nam tristique massa a vestibulum congue. Vivamus nisi felis, volutpat vitae neque quis, pharetra tristique massa. Duis tincidunt et nulla a hendrerit. Vestibulum in molestie lectus.")
```

Actual behavior:

[image: When big text]

[image: When a little text]

The text is cut off if there is a lot of it and if there is not enough of it, then there are huge margins between the edge of the window and the text, I want the window height to wrap the text, that is, the height of the window needs to be equal to the size of the text. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained in the [Layout Issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues) section of the layout documentation:

> The use of rich text in a label widget can introduce some problems to the layout of its parent widget. Problems occur due to the way rich text is handled by Qt's layout managers when the label is word wrapped".

Note that, as a rule of thumb, you shall never rely on the size hint of a label that uses word-wrapped text. This is related to the many problems text laying out has, like unexpected font behavior, system font scaling, high DPI settings. In reality, it's a **good** thing that the default behavior doesn't consider the possible size hint of a word-wrapped label, otherwise there could be serious performance issues, especially while resizing.

Truth is, word-wrapped text should always be displayed in a scroll area (using a QTextEdit or with a QLabel that is placed inside a QScrollArea); the default API cannot know the *infinite* possibilities in which some text could be shown, and should always aim for the best result with optimal performance.

The problem is caused by the fact that there's no way to know the "best" size hint of a label that can wrap its contents, and layout managers should always try to be as fast as possible in their response, otherwise you'd risk recursion or unnecessary overhead, even for a simple label.

***IF*** you are completely sure about the fixed width of the label, you should explicitly set it:

```py
self.label.setFixedWidth(230)
```

If the width cannot be known beforehand, due to the presence of other widgets in the layout that might change the available width for the label, then you can rely on the QLabel [`heightForWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#heightForWidth), set a minimum height for it based on the current width, and finally make a *delayed call* to the `adjustSize()` of the main window (the delay is required to allow the whole layout management to update the size hints).

```py
from random import randrange
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def randomText():
    return ' '.join(['Lorem ipsum'] * randrange(10, 50)) + '\n\nThe end.'


class TextWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedWidth(230)
        central = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(QToolButton())

        self.label = QLabel(randomText())
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)

        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Hello'), 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.setCentralWidget(central)

    def setMessage(self, message=''):
        self.label.setText(message or randomText())
        self.updateSize()

    def updateSize(self):
        self.centralWidget().layout().activate()
        self.label.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.label.setMinimumHeight(
            self.label.heightForWidth(self.label.width()))
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.adjustSize)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateSize()

app = QApplication([])
w = TextWindow()
QTimer.singleShot(1000, w.setMessage)
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the detailed answer, I understand your idea, maybe I won’t rely on the size hint of a label and put it in QScrollArea, I’ll think about it, but this window will be like a window with a message for the user, like ToastMessage, so even I don't know how best to do it. If for my window, the width should be fixed and the height will change depending on the text. If I use @Alexander's solution below, do I need to set setFixedWidth(230) on both the window itself and the QLabel?

Comment: Regarding setFixedWidth on QLabel, I figured it out, just below the answer from @Alexander

Comment: I copied your answer, but when there is only one line of text, for some reason the window does not fit tightly to the text and there are [indents on the top and bottom](https://imgur.com/mUhM3qW). I want the window to be as compact as possible in height. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I know what you want to do, I wouldn't answered if I didn't, and I obviously tested the code before posting it. Try with increasing the timer interval by a small fraction or call `updateSize` itself with a delayed timer.

Comment: Unfortunately increasing the timer interval or call updateSize itself with a delayed timer didn't help. I tried both on PyQt6 and PyQt5 and changed the scale in Windows 11 from 200% to 100%, but nothing helped. :(

Comment: if you remove adjustSize and just manually reduce the height after updateSize, then everything is fine, but adjustSize sets the height too high.

Comment: I can do instead of `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.adjustSize)` - `self.resize(self.centralWidget().layout().sizeHint())` but as you said "you shall never rely on the size hint of a label that uses word-wrapped text", so I hope you can help me to fix this `adjustSize` of the window.

Comment: How is the size of my window not equal to its sizeHint

Comment: It's not because you're trying to use the size hint of a widget that is **inside** the window, which has other widgets, contents margins and layout margins, and this is true especially for QMainWindow, which can have other decorations, and even a menubar or status bar. About this, if you do not need any of that, just use a plain QWidget, which is much simpler and, if I also recall correctly, has less issues with size hints and size adjusts.

Answer (score 1):

Get the size hint of the `QLabel` using the `sizeHint()` method and then use the result when you resize your window.

For example:

```
text = "Some very long text that will possible need to be wrapped and take up more than one line."

value = 3   # <--- raise or lower value to see adjustments

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.central = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)
        self.label = QLabel(text=text * value)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.resize(self.label.sizeHint())
```

Comment: If I do this only with text, then everything is OK, but if I add another QLabel for the icon to the text in the horizontal layout, then the text is cut off from above and below if there is a lot of it. Or if I add setContentsMargins then the text gets cut off too. How can this be resolved?

Comment: So far, if I add some widgets or margins to the layout in which the QLabel with text is located, then I must manually set its width, subtract all the padding in the layout and its child widgets from the window size and at the end self.resize(self.h_layout.sizeHint())

Comment: I mean smth like this
self.label_text.setFixedWidth(
            self.width()
            - self.h_layout.spacing()
            - self.h_layout.contentsMargins().left()
            - self.h_layout.contentsMargins().right()
            - self.label_icon.sizeHint().width()
        )

Comment: Note that this doesn't work properly if other widgets are in the layout or if the window and layouts have content margins (including borders added from stylesheet), as the label would always be cropped in certain cases.

Comment: @monotype  TBH I just took your example and tried a few things until i found something that worked.  musicmante answer is better